# Admin Grids not loading after upgrade to 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, grid, magento2.4.5

After upgrading from 2.3.4 to 2.4.5 (via composer) all areas in the admin that include the use of admin grids do not load (e.g. products, orders, blocks etc). No data is loaded and the spinner icon is where the grid should be.

The frontend loads fine.

The following file shows up as a 404 in chrome dev tools network tab: /static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/z-index.js

According to [this link](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/magento-open-source/2-4-4.html?lang=en), Magento 2.4.4 removed z-index.js as it is now included in jQuery UI v1.12.1. However when I view what version of jQuery UI my site is loading via the chrome dev tools network tab, its loading v1.10.4.

So I can only conclude that in this upgrade process some core Magento dependencies didn't get updated? But I'm not sure where to go from here?

Other things I have tried:

- reindexed the website
- checked that the frontend loads things like products etc
- disabled all third-party modules
- recompiled the website

My composer.json is below:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
            "magento/*": true
        },
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "2.4.5",
    "require": {
        "amasty/base": "^1.14",
        "amasty/module-google-rich-snippets": "^1.6",
        "eadesignro/module-eacore": "^0.3.1",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.12.1",
        "magefan/module-blog": "2.10.11.1",
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~2.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.5",
        "mollie/magento2": "^2.20",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.5.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~3.4.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.7",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.10.0",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.6.8",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~9.5.20",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.6.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "amasty": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://composer.amasty.com/community/"
        },
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use third party modules? If yes, disable these modules. Are the grids loading with disabled third party modules?

Comment: I've just tried disabled all third party and custom modules, leaving only Magento modules active (and recompiling everything... setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile etc). The admin grids still fail to load.